# Create the generated signed url without expiration time for Google cloud storage object

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to generate the signed url for the Google cloud storage object without expiration time. But when I am creating the signed url with V4 signing process, it is getting expired after seven days.

Is there any alternative to achieve this?

Also, what was the expiration time of V2 signing process?

Comment: @JohnHanley The only expiration limit for V2 is the size of int. V2 signed URLs can last for years. You can see the discussion [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/141763664). Either way, V4 is more standardized and users are advised to used this signing process.

Comment: @dondi - Thank you for that correction.

Comment: Thanks a lot and much appreciated both of you.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @DazWilkin's answer, it's not possible to create a Signed URL without expiration. The V2 signing process must accept a valid Unix Timestamp in seconds. You can enter up 64-bit Integer values but make sure that the timestamp is valid. There are tools out there that can convert timestamps to Datetime format.

If you try to set an invalid Unix timestamp, you'll get a `MalformedSecurityHeader` response.

However, if you insist on a Signed URL with expiration longer than a week, you can use the V2 signing process. As I mentioned in the comment, V2 signed urls can last for years.

If using the Client Library, first make sure to setup authentication first:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/path/to/keyfile.json"
```

Quick sample code (modified version of [V4 signing process](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-with-helpers#download-object)):

```
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)

url = blob.generate_signed_url(
  version="v2",
  # This URL is valid for 365 days
  expiration=datetime.timedelta(days=365),
  # Allow GET requests using this URL.
  method="GET",
)
```

Refer to [V2 Signing process](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls-v2) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The intent with Signed URLs is to provide (time-)limited access to a Cloud Storage URL.

Take away the time limitation and you may wish to consider just making the URL public.

Signed URLs are accessible to anything that has the URL. So, if you're concerned with discovery of guessable URLs (e.g. `my-bucket/my-object-path`) then you could consider obfuscating the object name, perhaps using base64-encoding to make the URL less-guessable although easily derivable:

`my-bucket/my-object-path` --> `my-bucket/bXktb2JqZWN0LXBhdGg=`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes Signed URLs is good but atleast is there any chance to increase the time span. And what will be max expiration time for v2 signing process ?